# Floating module on scrolling?

Tags: css, module-display, positions

Is there a way to create a module, which is floating in its position (and only in its position)?

http://aebb.es/4
here I would like to have the fixed opt-in module on the right side to float always on top of page during scrolling. But the module shall never leave the position "sidebar-right" on scrolling

Was thinking if it is solvable via CSS3? Also open for other solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the following (fetch first the 30% sidebar and define on page surround the visibility):

```
.g-block.size-30 #g-aside {
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
}

#g-page-surround {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

The second block of code is a small fix, as a `sticky` position won't work if any of the parent elements have a `hidden` overflow.

Hope this helps

Comment: big thx! adding minor fixes as edit, but your sample worked great! Was not aware of adding the visible to the page itself.

Comment: @laendle - oops, thanks for the edit. Glad it worked for you :)